# Positionning two div elements with one centered

Tags: html, css

I want to center a `div` element and to place another `div` element just on the right with the same vertical alignment. I don't know how to proceed without centering both elements.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>

.center {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KWsnh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `calc` to achieve this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KWsnh/15/)**

```
.container{
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
.center {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;  
    display: inline-block;
}

.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: calc(50% + 50px); // (100% - 100px)/2 + 100px (offset) = 50% + 50px
}
```

PS: [Browser support for calc](http://caniuse.com/calc) is quite good these days.

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/KWsnh/12/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='vcenter'>
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    display:table;
}
.container {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.center {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.vcenter {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```